# Google map doesn't load using codeigniter with googlemaps v3 library when I use an object property in the infowindow_content

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps-api-3

I have made a site with codeigniter and am using the [googlemaps v3 library](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library) to add markers to a map. I get the locations from my database as an array of objects, which I then loop through in a foreach adding the location to the map each time. If i enter a string as the infowindow_content everything is fine and the info bubble pops up with the string in when a marker is clicked. When I use a property of the location object though the map doesn't load.

Here is some example code:

```
    $this->load->library('Googlemaps');
    $towers = $this->towers_model->get_towers();

    $config['center'] = '18.557394170647473, -9.31640625';
    $config['zoom'] = '2';
    $this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

    foreach($towers as $tower) {
        $marker = array();
        $marker['position'] = $tower->Lat.', '.$tower->Long;
        $marker['infowindow_content'] = '<p>'.$tower->Dedicn.'</p>';
        $marker['icon'] = 'http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=A|9999FF|000000';
        $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
    }

    $this->data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();

    $this->template->write('scripts', $this->data['map']['js']);
    $this->template->write_view('content', 'towers/view_all', $this->data);
    $this->template->render();
```

As you can see I am trying to output $tower->Dedicn and when I do the map just won't load. I have echoed it out thought and its definately defined and contains content etc etc.

Comment: Separate each languange. Load the JSON data from controller, then write a Javascript simple function to retrieve the JSON data, and create the marker on the fly. With these method you can debug your code easily...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh I found out why! It's because some of the results had speech marks in them which interfered with the javascript so had to use str_replace to replace " with \" to escape them!